# Android Studio Project structure suddenly lost but files available?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]
I was working on the project, and the program was going high in CPU usage, so I closed and reopen the project.

After that, project structure is lost, I see "j" icon by the class names in the structure but I can't define TextViews, it doesnt recognize many things.

All files are there, but something is very wrong. What point should i look for? When i try to build project it says task CompileDebugSources not found in project app?

I am afraid that app updated something behind my back, like grade builder, and my project structure is somehow lost.. do anybody know how to restore it?

Trying to understand what is happening.

I get Language Level Changed pop-up if I try to copy the files in the new project?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is strange but it already happened to me but what i did was create the project again and push the old files onto the new project.

You can try to import the project to see if it works.

I hope i have helped a bit but still i will be trying to get a better anwser for you.

EDIT

Change the SDK to a level that you have installed in the SDK manager. The SDK manager can be accessed from `Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager`. For me, Android Studio was packaged with `API Level 17` but the new project wizard tried to target `API Level 18`.

Comment: Thanks, yes it's strange, I tried to push all files onto the new project and the same things happen.. I am afraid some update behind my back did this..

Comment: @Nikanor can you please had some screenshots of your project ?

Comment: @Nikanor What sdk is your project wizard trying to compile with and what version are you trying to compile with?

Comment: @Nikanor if you're trying to make a project with an SDk that you haven't got installed it might cause this issue if you can provide some more data i think we can help you :D

Comment: added screen shot above. how to check the versions?

Comment: It's actually problem with studio itself, it's not about project. As when I make new project I get the same crazy structure with "j" icons by the classes

Comment: @Nikanor In the src folder why is the AndroidTest folder a bigger name ?

Comment: @Nikanor Can you change your project view from Project Files to just Project or Android ?

Comment: ok check the first post.. Guys I am sure something happened to Android Studio itself.. it's not the project that is a problem.. I get the same problem with projects

Comment: Change the SDK to a level that you have installed in the SDK manager.  The SDK manager can be accessed from `Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager`.  For me, Android Studio was packaged with `API Level 17` but the new project wizard tried to target `API Level 18`.

Comment: the correct one is set..
I get this " Language Level Changed" when making new project

Comment: @Nikanor ok but do you have that version downloaded ?

Comment: yes there is 21.1.2 in the build.gradle and in SDK Manager for this version says installed

Comment: @Nikanor Do you have the means to reinstall Android Studio ? It should mantain all the SDKs you previosly installed but the IDE would be new

Comment: I will try to update API to latest version 23 to see what will happen.. If nothing happen I will reinstall studio

Comment: I had to do a complete uninstall and reinstall of Studio, then the program settle incompatible issues automatically. It was definitely something with API incompatibly that was causing issue.

Comment: @Nikanor well it's not allways good doing reinstalls cause it takes time but i'm glad you were able to fix your problem :D

Answer (score 1):

Click on the root directory of your project. Then go to VCS -> Show history -> revert back to the version which fits you. After that click in the gradle icon, it will refresh the project. Hope this helps.